# pm2 only show name and status for each process

Tags: pm2

so if I use "pm2 list" to show all added scripts it shows me a quite a lot of information about them.
But the only thing I want is the name and the status for each process.

```
Like this for example:
Name          Status
script1       Online
test123       Offline
abc           Online
```

Is there a way to get rid off all the other information?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
pm2 ls -m
```

Or to only display the status for each app:

```
pm2 ls -m | grep "+--\|status"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already found something that works for me but yours is like 100 times shorter.
But now I have a little other Problem so my output now is like this: 

name : test0
status : online
name: test1
status : online

how can I separate each app? 
for example like this:

name : test0
status : online
-------------------
name: test1
status : online

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 show "your id" | sed -n "7p" | cut -d "│" -f3
```

it works for me.